# SQL Query - Select closest Weather

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to get previous products sold that have the closest weather temp at time of sale to the current temp and weather_code. It may be easier to explain with an example tables and what I've tried.

tblSalesHistory:

```
 id             product_name
 ---------------------------
 2551           Product A
 2552           Product B
 2553           Product A
 2554           Product C
 2555           Product A
 2556           Product D
 2557           Product C
 2558           Product D
```

tblSalesExtraInfo:

```
 id   sale_id    weather_code   temp
 -------------------------------------------
 1      2551       122           0.00
 2      2552       122          17.00
 3      2553       152           6.00
 4      2554       160           6.00
 5      2555       012          24.00
 6      2556       012          16.00
 7      2557       122          16.00 
 8      2558       132          18.00
```

So let's just say the current temp is 16 and the current weather_code is 122. I would like get something like:

- Product D (It's not an exact match, but there are more records with a close average)
- Product C (Because the temp and weather_code are an exact match)
- Product B (Because the weather_code outranks the temp & temp is close)

The `weather_code` is irreverent unless its an exact match.

To get closest temp I've been using `ORDER BY ABS (temp - 16)` where 16 is the current temp. Apart from the ABS solution and perhaps I've just tired, but I don't think I've come close to the final solution so any input would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance

***Edit 2:*** 
I'm not really able to help with what I've already tried - I have just been trying a whole heap of things and haven't really gotten anywhere. Perhaps pseudocode might help explain what im struggling to portray?

---

```
SELECT AVG(temp), @weather_code_score, @temp_score FROM tblSalesExtraInfo  LEFT JOIN tblSalesHistory ON tblSalesExtraInfo.sales_id = tblSalesHistory.id GROUP BY product_name

ForEach Record

    IF (weather_code == @current_weathercode) { SET @weather_code_score += 10; }

    If (AVG(temp) IS BETWEEN (@current_temp + (@current_temp * .1))

        AND (@current_temp - (@current_temp * .1)) { SET @temp_score += 10; }

EndFor

ORDER BY temp_score + weather_code_score, ABS(temp - @current_temp)
```

---

So weather_code doesn't HAVE to be a match but if it is, it'll be weighted higher. The temp also doesn't have to be an exact match, but if the average is within let's say 10% of the current temp - weigh it higher.

This still isnt ideal, because it means an old item that has inevitably sold many of during all sorts of weather would probably always be higher than a new product that has only sold a couple of (even if the new item has only sold on exact weather_code and temp)- that said; once I have a start and some fresh eyes I can work on this later.

If i'm still not explaining it properly then I probably just need to go to bed and revisit tomorrow. :/

Comment: Please specify logic for how the various features of a sale should be weighted when ordering the results.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please, could you show your code for providing a context of your specific issue, at the time, you let other members see how far did you try?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Please see Edit 2. Perhaps this will help with the logic side

Answer (score 1):

Try below

```
WITH CTE
AS (
       (
           SELECT TOP 1 * 
           FROM   tblSalesExtraInfo a
                  INNER JOIN tblSalesHistory b
                       ON  b.id = a.sale_id
           WHERE  weather_code = currentweather_code
                  AND a.temp > current_temp
           ORDER BY
                  a.temp ASC
       )
       UNION ALL
       (
           SELECT TOP 1 * 
           FROM   tblSalesExtraInfo a
                  INNER JOIN tblSalesHistory b
                       ON  b.id = a.sale_id
           WHERE  weather_code = currentweather_code
                  AND a.temp <= current_temp
           ORDER BY
                  a.temp DESC
       )
   )
SELECT TOP 1 *
FROM   CTE
ORDER BY
       ABS(temp - current_temp) ASC
```